# “Elle était trop jeune pour s’en souvenir”: Does this phrase make sense from a temporal point of view?

Tags: sens, temps-grammatical

> On a assisté à la parade, ma nièce et moi, il y a cinq ans, mais **elle était trop jeune pour s’en souvenir**.

What I want to say here is:

> On a assisté à la parade, ma nièce et moi, il y a cinq ans, mais elle était trop jeune (***à l’époque***) pour s’en souvenir (***aujourd’hui***).

But considering that this clause starts with the *Imparfait* « était », I wonder if the part after « pour » must also refer to something that happened back then, at the same time as the *Imparfait* « était »:

> On a assisté à la parade, ma nièce et moi, il y a cinq ans, mais elle était trop jeune (***à l’époque***) pour s’en souvenir (***à l’époque***).

This does not make sense, of course...

Comment: *Elle était trop jeune pour comprendre* ? Mais *aujourd'hui*, elle comprendrait... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase makes sense. "pour s'en souvenir" is a *complément circonstanciel de conséquence* i.e it expresses the consequences of "elle était trop jeune".
There are nothing requiring the consequences to be at the same moment.

Also the phrase is not ambiguous:

- "elle était trop jeune" can only mean "elle était trop jeune il y a 5 ans", this is by the construction of the phrase.
- and "pour s'en souvenir" cannot be "il y a 5 ans" as it would not make any sense (that would mean she was remembering what she was living at the same time). Without any other time elements, it can only be understood as "pour s'en souvenir aujourd'hui".

Comment: Indeed; the semantics of these two verbs make the wrong interpretation very hard! I wonder if it would be possible to find a pair where it is a problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

The expression is sounding right enough to me, but yes the confusion is logically possible. If the context makes it unclear, or if one of the interlocutors is learning french, or anything alike, just go for the long version, saying out loud what you put between parenthesis, it's slightly heavier but correct also and clearer.

> On a assisté à la parade, ma nièce et moi, il y a cinq ans, mais elle était trop jeune à l’époque pour s’en souvenir aujourd’hui.

Comment: One could even spell out exactly what she is or isn't doing at the time in question: « Elle était trop jeune pour en former des souvenirs » ou quelque chose du genre.